# Gradually and randomly change colored image to grayscale in Java?

Tags: java, image, colors, grayscale

I have done some research and found some leads, but I am in need of help determining what is the best way to convert a color image to grayscale. Though there are plenty of examples for quick conversion, I am looking for a gradual AND random conversion. So, I am looking to display an image that, over time, becomes a grayscale image from 0-100% of the image surface to random pixels.

I don't need full code, just some methods, perhaps that will lead me in the right direction.

One idea I have is to have images with varying grayscale swapped in and out. Is this the best I can do? No real-time conversion?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: So, you want to know how to select a random pixel that has not be selected before and change it to grey scale? 0% 100% of all pixels selected sliding scale?

Comment: Show examples of what you have in mind.  Use a tool like gimp or photoshop to create them.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. So, I would like the image to gradually change from color to grayscale from 0 to 100% of its surface, but random pixels selected (to grayscale) each time as it goes from 0-100%. Hope that is clearer.

Comment: I can't think of any solution which doesn't involve keeping a progress value for each and every pixel.

Comment: you have to show what you want: in pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea as I understand it is gradual gray-ization; that is converge gradually to the gray-scale image. This can be achieved as said by converging to it; a convergence problem.

If the quantity is greater than the convergence value we decrease; if it is smaller we increase.

In the first loop we find the average (convergence value).

```
  int[] avg=new int[pix.length];
  for(i=0; i<wc; i++)
    for(j=0; j<hc; j++) {
      int p=bim.getRGB(i, j);
      int p1=(p&0x00ff0000)>>16, p2=(p&0x0000ff00)>>8, p3=p&0x000000ff;
      avg[i+j*wc]=(p1+p2+p3)/3;
    }
```

In the second loop we perform the convergence:

we increase/decrease each of the three color components until all converge: by a small step of 10 in this case you can choose the value.

If the value falls within one unit of convegence (e.g. less than 10) we set the value to the convergence value. If that happens for all pixels we reached gray scale.

```
boolean f1=false, f2=false, f3=false;
while(true) {
    f1=false; f2=false; f3=false;
    for(i=0; i<wc; i++)
    for(j=0; j<hc; j++) {
      int p=bim.getRGB(i, j);
      int p1=(p&0x00ff0000)>>16, p2=(p&0x0000ff00)>>8, p3=p&0x000000ff;
      if(p1>avg[i+j*wc]+10) { p1-=10; if(p1<avg[i+j*wc]) p1=avg[i+j*wc]; f1=true; }
      else if(p1<avg[i+j*wc]-10) { p1+=10; if(p1>avg[i+j*wc]) p1=avg[i+j*wc]; f1=true; }
      if(p2>avg[i+j*wc]+10) { p2-=10; if(p2<avg[i+j*wc]) p2=avg[i+j*wc]; f2=true; }
      else if(p2<avg[i+j*wc]-10) { p2+=10; if(p2>avg[i+j*wc]) p2=avg[i+j*wc]; f2=true; }
      if(p3>avg[i+j*wc]+10) { p3-=10; if(p3<avg[i+j*wc]) p3=avg[i+j*wc]; f3=true; }
      else if(p3<avg[i+j*wc]-10) { p3+=10; if(p3>avg[i+j*wc]) p3=avg[i+j*wc]; f3=true; }
      bim.setRGB(i, j, 0xff000000|(p1<<16)|(p2<<8)|p3);
    }
    if(f1 || f2 || f3) ; else   {    System.err.println("no change"); break; }
}
```

Comment: @gpash. I apologize if you didn't see my response to this below, but thank you! This is something I wouldn't have considered and fits my needs better than I originally thought about. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. This is what I have and what it does so far....

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.util.*;

public class Color2GrayscaleImage{
  public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What percent of the image do you want grayscaled?");

    int percentCover=input.nextInt();
    double per=(percentCover/100);
    BufferedImage img = null;
    File f = null;

    try{
      f = new File("media/mini0n.jpg");
      img = ImageIO.read(f);
    }catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    //get image width and height
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();

System.out.println(width+"x"+height+". "+width*height+ " total pixels.");

    //convert entire image to grayscale
    //for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
      //for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        //int p = img.getRGB(x,y);
        int num;
        for (num=0; num<5; num++){
        //randomly select pixels to be converted to grayscale
      for(int heightY = 0; heightY < height*(1+per); heightY++){
      for(int widthX = 0; widthX < width*(1+per); widthX++){

    Random random=new Random();
    int x= random.nextInt((width));
      int y= random.nextInt((height));

        int p = img.getRGB(x,y);

        int a = (p>>24)&0xff;
        int r = (p>>16)&0xff;
        int g = (p>>8)&0xff;
        int b = p&0xff;

        //calculate average
        int avg = (r+g+b)/3;

        //replace RGB value with avg
        p = (a<<24) | (avg<<16) | (avg<<8) | avg;

        img.setRGB(x, y, p);

        }
   }
    //write image
    try{
      f = new File("media/altered/new_IMAGE"+num+".jpg");
      ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", f);
    }catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }}
   num++;
  }
}
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uf9plmmrepvxfqi/gradual.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Sorry guys, this is the image. http://i.imgur.com/hb9Zb9L.jpg

Comment: ok the image shows what you want: that is not randomly changing gray scale pixels - it's gradual gray-ization - this is the effect as visible

Comment: @gpasch. Fantastic! Thank you! This is what I managed to get from your help. [link](http://imgur.com/xNMYAfs) I can certainly work with this!